# May 'repuired' as a top property key in a json schema not be an error?

Tags: java, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I use networknt:json-schema-validator 1.0.42.
I have been given a (intended) jsonschema with "repuired" (in stead of "required") as a top property key, in stead of a topmost key.
The schema factory (V7) happily ignores this and the validator then, of course, allows instance json not have the keys that were intended required.

I am surprised it can happen unless it is a bug.

I corrected the jsonschema concerning these two problems and added `"additionalProperties": false` just after the corrected and replaced line.
May be this part (the line I added) is missing in the metaschema but I suspect it may be for good, but don't know why, as I am new to JSON schema.

I prefer asking before filing a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON Schema spec (all drafts) says that unknown keywords are to be ignored.  The meta-schema not having `"additionalProperties": false` is correct.

I can't speak to this implementation specifically, but this is likely what's happening.

Comment: For weight, both myself and Greg Dennis are editors of the spec.